# warning on sortedArrayUsingSelector

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have the following line of code in my iPhone app:

```
[[sections allValues] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(sortSectionsBySectionName:)];
```

which generates a `Undeclared selector` warning.

All the objects in the array implements `sortSectionsBySectionName:`, so everything works as expected. I would, however, like to get rid of the warning.

Is there any way to tell the compiler that, the objects will indeed implement the selector? casting or something similar?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The method used should be publicly visible to the class using it. That generally means either:

1. Add `sortSectionsBySectionName:` to the .h file of the objects in the array and `#import` the .h file in this controller
2. Add a category on the objects in the array class, in the top of this controller, and define the `sortSectionsBySectionName:` method there

Once the compiler can see the existence of the method within the scope you're trying to use it you should be good.

Alternatively, ask the compiler to ignore it:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wundeclared-selector"

[[sections allValues] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(sortSectionsBySectionName:)];

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

but beware that this (and the category approach) could both hide issues that will cause problems at runtime...

Comment: The method is already visible in the scope. I think the problem is that the compiler can't know what kind of objects the NSArray contains

Comment: yeah, I thought about suppressing the warning, but I would really like another approch